# What is the correct date parser format string for the ISO date format?

Tags: python, date, python-2.7, date-parsing

I am trying to parse dates in the ISO date format, but for reasons I don't understand, the pattern I am using isn't working.

From the shell:

```
>>> s
datetime.date(2014, 1, 3)
>>> str(s)
'2014-01-03'
>>> datetine.strptime(str(s),"%y-%m-%d").date()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (date_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2014-01-30' does not match format '%y-%m-$d'
```

But `2014-01-03` should be a match to `%y-%m-%d`, right? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Capital `Y` for a 4 digit year - eg: `%Y-%m-%d`. What exactly are you trying to achieve anyway? It's odd to take the str rep of a date only to convert it to a datetime, then take the date back...

Comment: @JonClements it should be ab answer. what does small means?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan lower case `y` is 2 digit year... See [this site](http://strftime.org/) for info... Or the [official docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: @JonClements thanks, its almost same as I have been [used in C](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rtref/strpti.htm) also

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan it's based on the C library :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) (emphasis mine):

> **%y** Year **without century** as a zero-padded decimal number.   00, 01, ..., 99
>   **%Y**  Year **with century** as a decimal number.  1970, 1988, 2001, 2013

Therefore `%y-%m-%d` is expecting `14-01-03` while you have `2014-01-03` which requires `%Y-%m-%d`.

Answer (score 3):

Difference between upper and lower case:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2014-01-03', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
datetime.date(2014, 1, 3)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('14-01-03', '%y-%m-%d').date()
datetime.date(2014, 1, 3)
```

Documented in [strptime and strftime behavior](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).